Transfer apps between profiles
I can't find up to date info on this. Old advice doesn't work on newer androids and family link app.
I'm on Android 13.
I'm finding it hard setting up a child profile and using FL app in general a huge PITA. I even had to call Google and hard reset the tablet at one point!
Current issue is I have child using my own profile whilst I try to sort out theirs. So they have apps on my profile.
I want an easy way to transfer these apps (or allow permission or whatever method) to allow them to use certain (their) apps on their profile without them having to access my profile and without me having to manually download and authorise each app one by one to their profile.
It really should be intuitive as it's an obvious thing to want to do. But it isn't. In general as I said I find FL app and Android settings in general not intuitive to use. I don't find that the settings or FL app menu "titles" direct you properly to what you want to do. Eg can't find it in "apps" or "permissions" or "parental controls" all of which would be good places to put an "allow child profile access to app" or "transfer apps between profiles" button/slider/menu 
Many thanks for any help.
Edit:removed follow up question

If Google cant do it, then we probably cant either.

Don't be so negative - believe in yourself! Google was a different setup issue.
